# Qt in Clion 2020.3

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake

I was trying the new fearture in CLion 2020.3 - creating Qt Widgets Application. When I tryed to build a simple program that CLion offered me I got this error:

```
====================[ Build | untitled | Debug ]================================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.3.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build "C:\Users\vladi\CLionProjects\Second sem\untitled\cmake-build-debug" --target untitled
[ 25%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target untitled
[ 25%] Built target untitled_autogen
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable untitled.exe
LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1427~1.291\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\untitled.dir\objects1.rsp /out:untitled.exe /implib:untitled.lib /pdb:C:\Users\vladi\CLionProjects\Second sem\untitled\cmake-build-debug\untitled.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:X86 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console D:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\lib\Qt5Widgetsd.lib D:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\lib\Qt5Guid.lib D:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\lib\Qt5Cored.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\untitled.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\untitled.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ­ ©вЁ гЄ § ­­л© д ©«NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.3.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" : возвращенный код "0xffffffff"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe" : возвращенный код "0x2"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe" : возвращенный код "0x2"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe" : возвращенный код "0x2"
Stop.
```

Has no idea what is wrong

Comment: Are you able to translate your error messages into English?

Comment: Which ones? Like "Возвращаемый код"? - This means "return code". The mess of the symbols at the begining I tryed to fix, but actually I suppose it is the part of my problem, it doesn't seem to be an encoding truoble.

Comment: Suddenly it showed such error: "fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'"

Comment: That means you are mixing 32 bit and 64 bit. You can't mix and match the two. If your third party library (Qt) is 32 bit your application must be 32 bit. Same goes for 64 bit.